# lapack C code for matrix inversion

Tags: lapack

I am programming in c to implement the matrix inversion by calling zgetrf and zgetri routines. Here I tried two different matrices, M and N. The weird part is that M works perfectly but when I added N in the code, it shows segmentation fault. I already use matlab to calculate the result, and the availability of N is totally fine. Anyone could help me out? Thank you.

[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK8ru.png)

Comment: Hi, I fix it, and just let you know in case anyone is facing the same problem as me.  I change the ipiv declaration from int* ipiv to int ipiv, and pass &ipiv to the subroutine zgetrf and zgetri, and then everything works. Still don't know how come this happens.  Looking forward to any explanation from someone. Thank you!!

Comment: Hello again, I guess I figured out what is going here. If I declare the variable as pointer but not initialize it, it will be assigned a random piece of memory, which could easily cause a bug. If I declare it as int but not initialize it, it will be assigned a default value, say 0, and a confirmed piece of memory. This segmentation fault is reported as I am lucky enough, while if I am not, that will trash data without even knowing it!!